# How to create a new Directory in GITHUB?

Tags: git, github, directory

I have a code repository in Github. I tried adding a new directory in the codebase using the command:
git add CodeRevision where CodeRevision is a new directory. 
I got "fatal: pathspec 'CodeRevision/' did not match any files" message. Is it not possible to add a new directory in GIT?

Comment: Git only tracks files, not directories.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to commit a directory into a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573883/how-to-commit-a-directory-into-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 3):

[Git does not track empty directories](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Can_I_add_empty_directories.3F). Some people put a `.gitkeep` inside of the otherwise empty directories they want to track.

Or you could include a `.gitignore` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/932982/1272394).

It really begs the question: If it's empty, why track it? But that's for you to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Git only tracks files, not directories.

If you put a file in the directory and add that, the directory will automatically exist.

But there is no way to create an empty directory in git.

Comment: Could this be a new file?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I have a directory

Comment: See, I have a folder/directory 'CodeRevision' with 20-odd files inside a directory structure Dashboard/DAM_Application/Alerts/. I want to take it one level up to Dashboard/DAM_Application/. Now at this one level up I do not have any CodeRevision directory. So, I am not able to figure out how i can do this.

Comment: So make a directory and move files there

Comment: 'make a directory' - which means a new directory, right? then how do i add this new directory inside Dashboard/DAM_Application?

Comment: Using the filesystem.  Move files where to where you want them to be, then add those files to git.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add empty directories into your Git repository. See: [How can I add an empty directory to a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

You need to have content (i.e. a `.gitkeep`, `.gitignore`) inside the directory for Git to track.